# How to solve the "repeatSeparator" problem without a loop in Java?

Tags: java

There is a problem on CodingBat called *[repeatSeparator](https://codingbat.com/prob/p109637)*.

```
Given two strings, word and a separator sep, return a big string made of count occurrences of the word, separated by the separator string.

repeatSeparator("Word", "X", 3) → "WordXWordXWord"
repeatSeparator("This", "And", 2) → "ThisAndThis"
repeatSeparator("This", "And", 1) → "This"
```

I know how to solve it but my solution and most solutions I find on the internet uses a loop. Is there a way to solve this problem without a loop?

A pseudocode of my need `return (word+rep)*count;` which won't work but is there a way to achieve similiar result?

I'd highly value any reply.

Comment: Just like many other problems, there is no constant time solution to this. There may be ways to make it run faster, but it will still be O(N).

Comment: How about recursion?

Comment: even if there would be some fancy syntax to write this, it would not be `O(1)` the loop would just be hidden

Comment: Hi, if there is a way to avoid loop but still have O(n) complexity that's fine!!

Comment: Which version of Java? In nearly every new version, methods are added to class `String`. Would you consider using Apache's `StringUtils` class or another, similar third party library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One liner using Java 11:

```
String repeatSeparator(String word, String sep, int count) {
    return (word + sep).repeat(count-1) + word;
}
```

One liner using Java 8:

```
String repeatSeparator(String word, String sep, int count) {
    return String.join(sep, Collections.nCopies(count, word));
}
```

Comment: I've never used Java 11 before and it seems like cheating compared to other replies, nonetheless this is indeed what I've been looking for!

Comment: Finally, you've got the credit which you deserved. I feel happy about it.

Comment: Downloaded Java 11 and tested it; Works nicely; Thank you!

Comment: @unobatbayar I have also added a version for java 8 just in case if you want to use java 8.

Comment: That's absolutely insane

Answer (score 4):

If you absolutely want to hide the loops in the implementation, you could do something like this:

```
public String repeatSeparator(String word, String separator, int count) {
    return IntStream.range(0, count)
        .mapToObj(i -> word)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(separator));
}
```

The code above generates the numbers between 0 and count-1, replaces each number with the given word and finally concatenates them with the given separator.

Note that this still uses loops, they're just hidden inside the streams. Worse still, this solution is almost certainly way less efficient than a naive StringBuilder+for solution.

Edit: A (potentially) simpler version of the same idea:

```
public String repeatSeparator(String word, String separator, int count) {
    return Stream.generate(() -> word)
        .limit(count)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(separator));
}
```

Create an infinite stream of the word, limit it to the given count, then concatenate them with the separator.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by the combined use of the following methods/functions:

1. [Arrays::fill](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object))
2. [String::join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...))

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(repeatSeparator("Word", "X", 3));
        System.out.println(repeatSeparator("This", "And", 2));
        System.out.println(repeatSeparator("This", "And", 1));
    }

    static String repeatSeparator(String word, String separator, int n) {
        String[] arr = new String[n];
        Arrays.fill(arr, word);
        return String.join(separator, arr);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
WordXWordXWord
ThisAndThis
This
```

If you are allowed to use Java11, you can use [String:repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) as follows:

```
static String repeatSeparator(String word, String separator, int n) {
    return (word + separator).repeat(n - 1) + word;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in a comment and in @ackdari's answer, you can use a recursion. I suggest the [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) method:

```
static String repeatSeparator(String word, String separator, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return word;
    } else {
        String s = repeatSeparator(word, separator, n / 2); // half the expected string
        String ret = s + separator + s; // concatenate both halves
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            ret += separator + word; // if there's an odd number of words, add the last word.
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Although the time complexity seems to be `O(lg n)`, that's not the case unless the operations on strings (copy, concatenate) are atomic. And this code will probably be slower than the code of the other examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to avoid using a loop you can simply do an recursion.
Since this is somekind of exceris I will just brifly outline a solution.

To find a recusive solution to a problem you first have to find the base case(s).
The problem of joining a string with a seperator has two base cases.

- repeat the word zero times
- repeat the word one time

Now, to create a recursive solution you have to somehow reduce the case *repeat the word `n` times* to *repeat the word `m` times*  where `m < n`.

Answer (score 2):

One solution with `Collections.nCopies`

```
String repeatSeparator(String word, String separator, int count) {
    return Collections.nCopies(count, word).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(separator));;
}
```